# Is there a way to read file from Azure DevOps YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, csproj

When doing my CI on Azure DevOps with the YAML file format, I'm trying to read my csproj files to extract informations about version to create NuGet packages that will follow the csproj version.

I'm using `NuGetCommand@2` for packaging (because of `versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber`)

Is there a built-in task or a way to extract this info from csproj file as a regex and pass them to `NuGetCommand@2`?

Answer (score 12):

I'm fairly sure there is nothing built-in for this, but you can use any scripting language you like to parse the file and "spit out" whatever you need as a build variable and consume it later on. here's what I've been doing:

```
- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dp]$(cat $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/deployment/dp)"
- script: az group delete -n $(dp)-k8s -y --no-wait
```

you can obviously do any custom thing in the script step and consume the result in anyway you like to.

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: Ok so, I'll try to do this in js when I have time

Comment: Good question, and need the same - did you get anywhere with this and can an example be posted to extract major.minor.patch version info from csproj?

Answer (score 7):

## Linux-based agent solution

You can add this as a first step to extract the  tag of a csproj :

```
- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]$(cat 'ProjectDirectory/MyProject.csproj' | grep -oP '(?<=<Version>).*?(?=<\/Version>)')"
```

You will then be able to use it by calling `$(version)` anywhere in your yaml.

## Explanation :

- `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]` means "set a variable that I can use after"
- `cat 'ProjectDirectory/MyProject.csproj' | grep` gets your csproj content then pass it to grep so we can exec a regular expression on it
- `(?<=<Version>).*?(?=<\/Version>)')` is a regular expression that finds the `<Version>x.x.x</Version>` tag without consuming the tags so it only prints what is inside

Comment: Tried this but the build failed with the following error: `grep: -P supports only unibyte and UTF-8 locales`

Comment: Are you in a linux-based build agent ?

Comment: Yes this solution is for a linux-based agent. I will add it to my post.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers here didn't work for me, but I did cobble together an alternative solution in my pipeline definition:

```
variables:
  projectVersion: '0.0'
  buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  versionNumber: '$(projectVersion).$(buildNumber)'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $input_path = (Get-ChildItem -Path "YourDirectory\" -Include SampleLibrary.csproj -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
      $regex = '(?<=<Version>).*?(?=<\/Version>)'
      $version = Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
      Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectVersion]$version"
```

This will set the version number to a nice value like '1.1.8.547', although obviously you can omit the build number if you prefer.

The gist of the PowerShell script here is that it will first retrieve the .csproj file in the specified directory. Then I used the same regex that Francoimora posted to pull the value out of the file and stored it in the $version variable. The last line is writing the value of $version to the projectVersion variable defined in the YAML.

Removing the AssemblyInfo.cs file from class libraries in .NET Standard really seems to have been a whole lot of trouble and nothing gained... Hopefully we'll get some better pipeline tasks/variables that are suited to these kinds of projects in the future.