# How to read contents from Dockerfile in azure-pipeline.yaml file?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I have environment variable set in `Dockerfile` which is in Azure Repos part of the project. I have to set up Docker based pipeline in Azure Pipeline. I'm trying to get the environment variable content in `azure-pipelines.yaml` file.

Is it possible to access `Dockerfile` contents in `azure-pipelines.yaml` file?

Can we pass argument value (Environment value) to `azure-pipelines.yaml` file?

Please guide!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: @LinPy Thanks! Is it possible to pass the values outside of `azure-pipelines.yaml` file? Passing the values runtime when creating the `azure-pipelines.yaml` file.

Comment: In the [Docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) there's an attribute `Dockerfile` which allows you to access docker file with its file path. Also check [Is there a way to read file from Azure DevOps YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54541789/12722389) for information about how you can read files content in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an environment variable both when building your docker image **and** elsewhere in the pipeline, I'd suggest restructuring:

1. add a [build variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) to your pipeline, defining your environment variable; this will make it accessible to every task in your pipeline
2. remove the environment variable from the dockerfile
3. replace it with an [ARG value](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg), so your docker build step can pass in a [--build-arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) parameter, specifying the build variable

Comment: Thanks! Can we name the pipeline as azure-pipelines-dev, azure-pipelines-qa, azure-pipelines-uat in this format?

Comment: Rather than having multiple pipelines, I think it would be a better system to have a single pipeline but with variables passed in which make it run slightly differently for dev, for qa, for uat, etc.

Comment: Can you please provide examples?

Comment: There are some good examples in the docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch